# How to view live code coverage in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio Enterprise. At the linked timestamp, [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DwbYxP-etMY&t=500s) has green little checkmarks on the left side of his window that seem to show code coverage in real time.

How do I turn this on?

[image: image of the feature]

I tried searching all over, but I don't know what this setting is called.

Comment: this feature  (live unit testing) is available in the enterprise version of Visual Studio, Another cool plugin that does the same work is NCrunch.

Comment: see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/live-unit-testing

Answer (score 0):

This feature is only available on Visual Studio Enterprise Edition.

After establishing the corresponding class library and unit test method, you can pass

Test=>Live Unity Testing=>Start

[image]

Conduct Live Unity Testing.

[image]

For detailed steps, please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/live-unit-testing-start?view=vs-2022

As you develop your application, Live Unit Testing automatically runs any affected unit tests in the background and displays the results and code coverage in real time. When code is modified, live unit testing provides feedback on how the changes affect existing tests and whether the new code added is covered by one or more existing tests.

Comment: I have run live unit testing, but I see no green checkmarks next to my tests.

Comment: @SIT_account If your operation steps are OK, you need to delete the .vs folder in the project directory (this is a hidden folder). Then try starting the live unit test again